# Expansion of $\sin m \theta$ in power of $\sin \theta$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

After completing successive differentiation, I stumbled upon a problem. I have to expand $\sin m \theta$ in power of $\sin \theta$.

Now, when I did Taylor's theorem, when we expand
$$f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + \left(\frac{h^2}{2!}\right)f''(x) + \ldots $$
we do it in powers of $h$, that I understand.

So, I wanna know what does in the *power* of $\sin \theta$ means here. Can you tell me by expanding it.

Comment: You are supposed to write $\sin (m\theta)$ as $p(\sin \theta)$ where $p$ is a polynomial.

Comment: I am not sure that this can be done. Indeed, it can probably be done for $\sin m \theta$ when $m$ is odd, but not when $m$ is even (e.g. try $m=2$).

Comment: A power of $\sin \theta$ is something like $(\sin \theta)^5$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. I dont quite get it. See, as in Taylor's theorem, $f(x+h)$, do you know what should x and h be substituted for above problem?

Comment: @ Teresa Lisbon. How so?

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip. I dont actually get your answer's connection with the question.

Comment: forget Taylor's theorem, that's not the relevant issue here. For example, using the triple angle identities, one has $\sin(3\theta)=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$. Meaning if you define $p(x)=3x-4x^3$, this is a cubic polynomial and we have $\sin(3\theta)=p(\sin\theta)$. As mentioned above, you can't do this for all $m$ (because $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, and one cannot express $\cos\theta$ as a polynomial in $\sin\theta$... but we can always expand $\sin(m\theta)=f(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ for some polynomial $f(x,y)$ in two variables).

Comment: @arnav You asked what "power of sine" means.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(2nx) =(-1)^{n-1} \cos x\left\{2^{2n-1}\sin^{2n-1} x-\frac{2n-2}{1!}2^{2n-3}\sin^{2n-3}x + \frac{(2n-3)(2n-4)}{2!}2^{2n-5}\sin^{2n-5}x - \frac{(2n-4)(2n-5)(2n-6)}{3!}2^{2n-7}\sin^{2n-7}x+\cdots
\right\}.
$$
$$ \sin[(2n-1)x] = (-1)^{n-1}\left\{2^{2n-2}\sin^{2n-1}x-\frac{2n-1}{1!}2^{2n-4}\sin^{2n-3}x +\frac{(2n-1)(2n-4)}{2!}2^{2n-6}\sin^{2n-5}x -\frac{(2n-1)(2n-5)(2n-6)}{3!}2^{2n-8}\sin^{2n-7}x+\cdots
\right\}.
$$
This is from the book of E. P. Adams and R. L. Hippisley, "Smithsonain Mathematical Formulae..." (1922) as reprinted in the book of Gradsteyn and Ryzhnik.